# How can I have multiple commit buttons for a form in formtastic in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, button, formtastic

I have a form and am using Formtastic.  I want to have two options for the button and to store the value selected in the newly created record.

Would I do something like this?

```
<%= form.buttons do %>
  <%= form.commit_button :value => "Give" %>
  <%= form.commit_button :value => "Request" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try assigning a `:name` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`commit_button()` takes a first argument as a String, or, to match the `input()` API, it also accepts a `:label` option. These two are functionally equivalent:

```
<%= f.commit_button :label => "Save" %>
<%= f.commit_button :label => "Save and Continue Editing" %>

<%= f.commit_button "Save" %>
<%= f.commit_button "Save and Continue Editing" %>
```

There's no APIs yet for cancel buttons, reset buttons, etc. You can also use standard Rails helpers like link_to and puts some mark-up around them:

```
<%= f.buttons do %>
  <%= f.commit_button :label => "Save" %>
  <li class="cancel">
    <%= link_to "Cancel", foos_path %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `commit_button` was deprecated in 2.1.0. How would I do this with the latest formtastic?

Answer (score 0):

The commit_button has been removed from the api.  I implemented this by setting the name and value for the button in the button_html.

```
f.actions do
  f.action :submit, :as => :button
  f.action :submit, :as => :button, label: 'Save and Next', button_html: {name: 'boo', value: 'bah'}
  f.action :cancel, :as => :link, label: 'Cancel', class: 'cancel', wrapper_html: {class: :cancel}
end
```